# Variables not recognized in an Execute SQL task

Tags: ssis

1. I have this sql statements running in my ssis package. I have hard coded the email address. How can i pass it as variable and externalize the variable and can pass the value from config file?
2. The `@PackageStartTime` is the system start time. I have declared that variable and set the expression in property window with `@[System::StartTime]` and evaluated that expression. But when i run this package and when it hits this particular task it get stuck at there saying `PackageStartTime` parameter is not recognized and result property is not set correctly.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @PackageStartTime Varchar(250) 
SET @PackageStartTime =?

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >= @PackageStartTime) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SUB Varchar(250) 
    SET @SUB = 'File Failed' + @@SERVERNAME

    DECLARE @BODY Varchar(250) 
    SET @BODY = 'File Failed' + @@SERVERNAME

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name='default',
    @recipients='dev@null.com', 
    @subject=@SUB, 
    @body=@BODY,
    @query= 'SELECT DISTINCT FileLoadName FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate  >= @PackageStartTime', 
    @attach_query_result_as_file=1
```

Any idea what to solve these two things?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maina, I just responded to your another post on this subject. You have three posts so far that I have encountered. The questions you have asked in this one are very general in nature and the answer can be found in any good book (such as Professional Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Integration Services). You can also find complete step-by-step answer on many websites (but do not use them as a replacement of a book; otherwise chances are your knowledge of SSIS will remain patchy.

With that said, here are two links that answer your questions:
1. Passing a variable: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/passing-variables-to-and-from-an-ssis-task/ (Actually, it appears I had sent this link to you earlier as well.)

1. Assigning variable values from config - http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/1655/passing-values-into-an-ssis-package-at-runtime-from-outside-the-package

Focus on item 1 first. After you have practiced it, create a new Execute sql task and put just his much code inside it:

DECLARE @PackageStartTime Varchar(40)=?;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >= @PackageStartTime;

and store this row count in a package variable iCount. Returning the value is done through ResultSet property. If you are able to make this task work, you have enhanced your proficiency in Execute SQL Task.